# where to find used dns settings

Tags: linux, dns, gentoo

my /etc/resolv.conf use 8.8.8.8
and all 3 dig below answers without a A reocrd

```
dig some_unregistred_adress.se
dig @8.8.8.8 some_unregistred_adress.se
dig @127.0.0.1 some_unregistred_adress.se
```

but if i ping some_unregistred_adress.se
i end up pinging my server, thats not even at the same ISP as this computer,
only connection i know is that this computers hostname is a subdomain of my server.

Where is ping and other softwhere geting the IP adresses from unregistered domains?

some relevant output:

```
puggan@rito ~ $ uname -a
Linux rito.work.puggan.se 2.6.38-gentoo-r6 #2 SMP Thu Jul 14 14:36:14 CEST 2011 i686 AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 245 Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux


puggan@rito ~ $ dig @127.0.0.1 some_unregistred_adress.se

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @127.0.0.1 some_unregistred_adress.se
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 8080
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;some_unregistred_adress.se.    IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec  2 15:51:31 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44


puggan@rito ~ $ ping -c 1 some_unregistred_adress.se
PING puggan.se (83.248.176.173) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from c83-248-176-173.bredband.comhem.se (83.248.176.173): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=34.4 ms

--- puggan.se ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 34.406/34.406/34.406/0.000 ms


puggan@rito ~ $ egrep "^(#|$)" -v /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 130.244.127.162
nameserver 130.244.127.170
nameserver 192.168.1.32
```

Comment: Anything in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: nothing relevant: egrep "^(#|$)" -v /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       guide.opendns.com
::1             localhost
83.191.245.100 maple-info.net
83.191.245.100 www.maple-info.net
83.254.38.187 mrzoom-egotripp

Comment: Marc B: yes, but dig should be catched to then, as opendns do, if i ran "dig @208.67.220.220 some_unregistred_adress.se" i get a false A record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are *not* using fully-qualified domain names;
2. your domain search path for converting names to FQDNs includes `puggan.se.`; and
3. there is a wildcard at `*.puggan.se` that matches `some_unregistred_adress.se.puggan.se.` and that has a `cname` resource record set pointing to `puggan.se`.

Use fully-qualified domain names if you don't want to use the search path behaviour that you have configured in your DNS client library.

### Further reading

- [fully qualified domain name](http://www.menandmice.com/knowledgehub/dnsglossary/fqdn/default.aspx).  Men and Mice.  2009.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003).  [Why the results from `nslookup` are different to the operation of `ping`](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/nslookup-results-different-to-ping.html).  Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 2):

Some ISPs intercept DNS requests and redirect them to their own, and serve up bad answers (e.g. their own spamvertising sites) in the hopes of making a few pennies off nonexistent/mis-typed domains.

As well, whoever's running the .se TLD can also have a wildcard *.se DNS entry to catch all non-existent .se domain lookups as well. For .se, this seems to be "one.com":

```
$ nslookup -type=soa blahblah.se
Server:  access.usask.ca
Address:  128.233.3.1

Non-authoritative answer:
blahblah.se
        primary name server = ns01.one.com
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.one.com
        serial  = 2004000000
        refresh = 10800 (3 hours)
        retry   = 1800 (30 mins)
        expire  = 1209600 (14 days)
        default TTL = 900 (15 mins)

blahblah.se     nameserver = ns01.one.com
blahblah.se     nameserver = ns02.one.com
ns01.one.com    internet address = 195.47.247.5
ns02.one.com    internet address = 91.198.169.5</strike>
```

ok... should've picked a way more random/non-existent domain for this particular test. nslookup asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsf.se does return no-such-host.

Comment: nslookup -type=soa some_unregistred_adress.se
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find some_unregistred_adress.se: NXDOMAIN

Comment: blahblah.se is a reigistred doamin, owned by HENRIK FORSELL

Comment: for asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsf.se dig and nslookup give no a record, and ping gives me the same ip as my server

Comment: ping should be using the system resolver settings, so ping/telnet/traceroute/ssh/etc... should all get the same IP when they look it up.

Comment: they all have the same problem, but programs like dig and nslookup don't, and they use /etc/resolv.conf, so what backup plan are the system resolver using, i guess its using my hostname somehow, and i want to turn it off

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem again, 
forgot to write my soulution last time.

to turn off search domain i added `search .` in /etc/dhcpcd.conf (gentoo)